# html container not found at createChild in amCharts Angular

Tags: angular, amcharts4, ngoninit

In here when i am in the same page it loads the chart.But when i click another page and again come to this page chart is not loading and it shows like  **html container not found
at createChild** [image]

But if i again reload the same page chart will appear.

This is my component.ts file.

```
constructor( private zone: NgZone) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {

          this.drawingChart();
    });
  }

drawingChart() {
    am4core.useTheme(am4themesAnimated);
    const container = am4core.create('div1', am4core.Container);
    container.width = am4core.percent(100);
    container.height = am4core.percent(100);
    const chart = container.createChild(am4charts.XYChart);
    chart.padding(0, 0, 0, 0);

    chart.data = [
      {
        date: '2012-07-27',
        value: 13
      },   {
        date: '2012-12-28',
        value: 50
      }, {
        date: '2012-12-29',
        value: 51
      }, {
        date: '2013-01-30',
        value: 81
      }];
    chart.colors.list = [
      am4core.color('rgba(4, 69, 142, 1)'),
    ];

    const dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
    const valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

    valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
    valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
    dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
    dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;

    const series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
    series.dataFields.valueY = 'value';
    series.dataFields.dateX = 'date';
    series.tooltipText = '{value';
    series.fillOpacity = 1;
    series.strokeWidth = 2;
    series.minBulletDistance = 15;
  }
```

This is my html file

```
<div class="col-10 col-sm-3-2 col-md-3-2 col-lg-7-6">
  <div class="l-content-wrapper ">
    <div class="a-title">
      <div class="a-title-content">
        <div class="a-title-content-main">Chart</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div1" class="graph_area graph_area__500">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I could n't find the reason here

Answer (score 1):

When you code in **ngOnInit()** gets executed, till that time your html is not rendered, so when you want to access the **div1**, it gets undefined.

So try to move your code in **ngAfterViewInit()**. This should probably resolve your issue.
And if not you can try adding some timeout in that, so that till that time your div gets rendered.

Please refer the following code:

```
        ngOnInit() {
           
          }
        ngAfterViewInit(){
           this.getDiv()
       }
    getDiv(){
      if(!this.div){
        this.div = document.getElementById("div1");
        if(!this.div){
setTimeout(()=>{
         this.getDiv()
          },200)
          return
         }} 
        this.drawingChart();
   }
```

Comment: Why have you added this part in runOutsideAngular?

Comment: try to direcly call this.drawingChart in ngAfterViewInit()

Comment: Actually that thing also not working when i add timeout it delays & after that shows the error

Comment: `ngAfterViewInit() {

      this.cardCheckingsChart();

  }` put like this no error

Comment: but at the first reload it does n't show the chart.Again reload it shows the chart

Comment: @Hans Please suggest if you found any work around for this issue.facing the same issue with amcharts loading while navigating to multiple pages.

Comment: @Jay if we didn't dispose the charts properly sometimes this error comes

Answer (score 1):

putting the charts code inside ngAfterViewInit solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was calling my chart creation logic in `ngOnInit()` and got the html container not found, but after moving the chart drawing logic to `ngAfterViewInit()`, chart started displaying.